# How to bulk download historical weather data from Canadian government website using R

Tags: r, url, download

I'm trying to download climate data in bulk from [the Canadian Government's national weather and climate data reporting service](http://www.climate.weather.gc.ca) using R. Here are instructions provided via their website which explain how to do this using Cygwin, which I was able to do, however, I'd like to include the file retrieval as part of a script in R which iterates grabbing the data for multiple stations and time frames and processes them, etc.. I'm somewhat new to R, so I'm having trouble with this process.

> Readme.txt
>
> URL based procedure to automatically download data in bulk from Climate Website
>   `(http&colon;//www.climate.weather.gc.ca)`
>   Version: 2016-05-10
>
> ENVIRONMENT AND CLIMATE CHANGE CANADA
>
> To read this file online, please visit:
>   ftp://client_climate@ftp.tor.ec.gc.ca/Pub/Get_More_Data_Plus_de_donnees/
>
> Folder: Get_More_Data_Plus_de_donnees > Readme.txt
>
> Instructions on how to download all weather data for one station from Environment and Climate Change Canada's Climate website:
>
> A daily updated list of Climate stations in the National Archive, including their Climate ID, Station ID, WMO ID, TC ID, and co-ordinates can be found in the following folder:
>   Get_More_Data_Plus_de_donnees > Station Inventory EN.csv
>
> Use the following utility to download data:
>   wget (GNU / Linux Operating systems)
>   Cygwin (Windows Operating systems) `https&colon;//www.cygwin.com`
>   Homebrew (OS X - Apple)  `http&colon;//brew.sh/`
>
> Example to download all available hourly data for Yellowknife A, from 1998 to 2008, in .csv format
>
> Command line:
>
> for year in `seq 1998 2008`;do for month in `seq 1 12`;do wget --content-disposition "http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=1706&Year=${year}&Month=${month}&Day=14&timeframe=1&submit= Download+Data" ;done;done
>
> WHERE:
>   year = change values in command line (`seq 1998 2008`) 
>   month = change values in command line (`seq 1 12`)
>   format= [csv|xml]: the format output
>   `timeframe = 1`: for hourly data
>   `timeframe = 2`: for daily data
>   `timeframe = 3`: for monthly data
>   Day: the value of the "day" variable is not used and can be an arbitrary value 
>   For another station, change the value of the variable stationID
>   For the data in XML format, change the value of the variable format to xml in the URL.
>
> For information in French, change Download+Data with ++T%C3%A9l%C3%A9charger+%0D%0Ades+donn%C3%A9es, also change _e with _f in the url.
>
> For questions or concerns please contact our National Climate Services office at: 
>   ec.services.climatiques-climate.services.ec@canada.ca

As stated above, the Cygwin command is:

```
for year in `seq 2015 2018`;do for month in `seq 1 12`;do wget --content-disposition "http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=51459&Year=${year}&Month=${month}&Day=14&timeframe=1&submit=Download+Data" ;done;done
```

I know that `download.file()` has an option for `wget`, as is used by the Cygwin command, however, when I tried the following:

```
download.file("http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=51459&Year=$2018&Month=$12&Day=14&timeframe=2&submit=Download+Data","X:/folderX/example.csv", method = "wget")
```

I get a `'wget' call had nonzero exit status` error.

Not sure if this has something to do with `--content-disposition` from the Cygwin command or if I'm even approaching this with the right function or not, so any direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in using an existing package for this, specifically weathercan which is described here: http://ropensci.github.io/weathercan/

Comment: Thanks, @EmilyKothe! This solves my problem. I wish I knew about the `weathercan` package earlier.

Comment: @EmilyKothe, do you know where I could grab daily weather forecasts (7-day or 14-day)? Is this data accessible in a similar manner from weather.gc.ca?

Answer (score 1):

You are using http you need https.
You also have $ in front of your numbers.

What you have :
http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=51459&Year=$2018&Month=$12&Day=14&timeframe=2&submit=Download+Data

WORKING LINK:
https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=51459&Year=2018&Month=3&Day=31&timeframe=1

There is also some needed documentation for general use of the climate data such as the station list so you know where to request:
https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1egfzGgzUb0RFu_EE5AYFZtsyXPfZ11y2&export=download

You can find information on the columns here:
https://climate.weather.gc.ca/glossary_e.html#weather

And some general data information here:
https://climate.weather.gc.ca/about_the_data_index_e.html https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WJCDEU34c60IfOnG4rv5EPZ4IhhW9vZH

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything useful, at all, in the link you posted.  It seems to be some kind of landing page, but it doesn't contain any weather-related data.  Anyway, here is how to loop through an array of URLs, and download data from each.  Just modify it to suit your needs.

```
library(RCurl);library(XML)

pageNum <- seq(1:10)
url <- paste0("http://www.totaljobs.com/JobSearch/Results.aspx?Keywords=Leadership&LTxt=&Radius=10&RateType=0&JobType1=&CompanyType=&PageNum=") 
urls <- paste0(url, pageNum) 

allPages <- lapply(urls, function(x) getURLContent(x)[[1]])
xmlDocs <- lapply(allPages, function(x) XML::htmlParse(x))
```

Here is another example.

```
mydownload <- function (start_date, end_date) {
  start_date <- as.Date(start_date)  ## convert to Date object
  end_date <- as.Date(end_date)  ## convert to Date object
  dates <- as.Date("1970/01/01") + (start_date : end_date)  ## date sequence
  ## a loop to download data
  for (i in 1:length(dates)) {
    string_date <- as.character(dates[i])
    myfile <- paste0("C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/weather/", string_date, ".csv")
    string_date <- gsub("-", "-", string_date)  ## replace "-" with "/"
    myurl <- paste("https://sci.ncas.ac.uk/leedsweather/Archive/CUSTOM-ARC-", string_date, "-METRIC.csv", sep = "")
    download.file(url = myurl, destfile = myfile, quiet = TRUE)
    }
  }

mydownload("2013/11/25", "2013/11/30")
```

Comment: Sorry @ryguy72 for the delay, and thanks for posting an answer to my question. To get to the site with the readme.txt quoted above, you would click 'Historical Data' from the main page, then enter a station name (e.g. 'Toronto Intl') under 'Search by Station' and click 'Search'. From there click 'Go' and then click 'Get More Data' on the following page. The only reason I didn't include the end link from all that is because it brings you to an FTP site which, when I tried to open the link in a new tab gave me a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

As @EmilyKothe was saying, you can use the R weathercan package to download ECCC station data in bulk. I find it still a bit annoying since not everyone uses R.

So I built a Shiny web application based on weathercan functionality:
https://nickrongkp.shinyapps.io/WeatherCan/
The app is hosted on shinyapps.io (free account with limited running time) so please close the browser as soon as you are done for others' sake.

Source code:
https://github.com/nickyrong/ShinyWeatherCan